# loop the whole macro but with different "Input" each time?

Tags: automation, imacros

I am very very noob at this guys so please don't get mad at me  :oops:
I am using Imacros for Chrome.

1- I want to stop at the "current page" when the macro find the "keyword" that i am searching for in it.
2- I want to loop this macro but with different "Input" each time until the CSV file inputs ends but i don't know how to do that.

Here's what i have tried:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=http://gizaedu.gov.eg/natig/3.aspx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:TextBox1 CONTENT=10000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:Button1
SET EXTRACT NULL
'if this exist you extract the text(even if you know it)
'if doesn't exist should return error but we turned that off; Extract remains Null
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Keyword EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if(text==\"keyword\") text = \"jibber\"
'this one executes if the text is right, if not should give error but we turned that off
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:{{!VAR1}}
```

My main goal is to input multiple values from the CSV file and each time search the page for the "keyword" and if it's found then just stops and let me "view" the page and if it didn't find the "keyword" i want it to just keep going until the end of the CSV inputs.

I have found this code but i don't know where to place it and how to even use it:

```
SET !DATASOURCE key22.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
```

I have tried my best but that's what i have come up with i hope you help me to reach my goal.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Edit: thanks to Shugar i have done it to %90 but i still don't know where to enter the keyword that the macro will stop when it sees it? here's the last script that i operated successfully!:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\SparkedLeads\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\01.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:{{!COL1}} EXTRACT=TXT
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
' press "OK" in the iMacros extract dialog after "viewing" the page if you want to continue playing the macro
' uncomment the line below if you want to break the macro when some keyword is found
SET E EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}' == '{{!COL1}}' ? MacroError('Keyword is found !') : '';")
URL GOTO=http://gizaedu.gov.eg/natig/3.aspx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:TextBox1 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:Button1
```

No problem guys i have figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Play the given below macro in loop mode at the  "current page". Pay attention to the comments inside.

```
SET !DATASOURCE key22.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:{{!COL1}} EXTRACT=TXT
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

' press "OK" in the iMacros extract dialog after "viewing" the page if you want to continue playing the macro
' uncomment the line below if you want to break the macro when some keyword is found
'SET E EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}' == '{{!COL1}}' ? MacroError('Keyword is found !') : '';")
```

Comment: thank you very much Shugar i have done it but i don't know where to enter the "keyword" that the macro will stop when see it?